# How do you get Canvas.SetTop to work on ItemsCollection items?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, observablecollection, itemscontrol

Below is the complete program (XAML and code behind).  When started you will see:
[image]

When you click [Show/Hide] you see:
[image]

When you uncheck Home and Documents and click [Apply] you see:
[image]

As you can see, the Home and Documents folder disappear, but the other folders do not move up. Looking at the two list boxes you see three items per line, folder label, the value for Canvas.SetTop, and True: Visibility.Visible or False: Visibility.Collapsed.  The Original Placement list box are the original values.  Each time you click [Apply] the New Placement List box shows that new values.  The Visibility value gets applied and the result is visible, either the folder is there or it is not.  However, applying the Canvas.SetTop does not work.  And you can see that the values have changed for the Canvas.SetTop.  And, if you look at the code, you see that it is applied to the same UIElement as the Visibility is applied to:

```
                    var f = Me[i];
                    Canvas.SetTop(iec, f.Top);          // Why does this not work and
                    iec.Visibility = f.FolderVisible;   // this does work?
```

I need the folders that are visible to move up to take the place of those that are collapsed.  Canvas.SetTop is not working.  How can I get the Folders to move?

Here is the Solution Explorer pane so that you know what is needed:
[image]

Here is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="FolderTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FolderTest"
        Title="Folder Test"
        Width="450"
        Height="410">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <!-- Folder Show/Hide Button -->
                <Button Name="FolderOptions" Content="Show/Hide" FontSize="8" FontWeight="Bold" Width="50" Height="20" Margin="116, 0, 0, 0" Click="Event_ShowHide_ButtonClick" />
                <!-- Folders -->
                <Grid>
                    <Canvas Name="xFolders"
                            Width="170"
                            Height="309"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Margin="0,10,0,0">
                        <Canvas.Resources>
                            <local:Folders x:Key="myFolders" />
                        </Canvas.Resources>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myFolders}}">
                            <ItemsControl.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.Template>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <Canvas />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate.Resources>
                                    </DataTemplate.Resources>
                                    <Canvas Name="FolderCanvas"
                                            Tag="{Binding Path=Number}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding Path=FolderVisible}">
                                        <Path Data="{Binding Path=FolderPath}"
                                              Stroke="{Binding Path=Brush}"
                                              Fill="{Binding Path=Brush}"/>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                    Canvas.Left="5"
                                                    Canvas.Top="2">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label}"
                                                       FontSize="12"
                                                       Margin="20, 0, 0, 0" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style>
                                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"
                                            Value="{Binding Top}" />
                                </Style>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Canvas>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0">
                <TextBlock Text="Original Placemet:" />
                <ListBox Name="OriginalPlacement" />
                <Button Name="Refresh" Content="New Placemet:" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" Click="Event_OriginalPlacement_ButtonClick" />
                <ListBox Name="NewPlacement" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the C# Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace FolderTest
{
    public struct GD
    {
        public static MainWindow MainWindow = null;
        public static Button Refresh = null;
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            GD.MainWindow = this;
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
        }

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GD.Refresh = Refresh;
            Folders.Placement(ref OriginalPlacement);
        }

        private void Event_ShowHide_ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var pu = Folders.FolderShowPopUp();
            pu.PlacementTarget = FolderOptions;
            pu.IsOpen = true;
        }

        private void Event_OriginalPlacement_ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Folders.Placement(ref NewPlacement);
        }
    }

    public class Folder
    {// Specification for each folder tab seen on the left.
        public int Number { get; set; }                         // Folder sequence number top to bottom starging with 1.
        public string Label { get; set; }                       // The label that appears on the folder tab itself.
        public double Top { get; set; }                         // Position of the upper left corner of this folder.
        public SolidColorBrush Brush { get; set; }              // Solid Color Brush.
        public string FolderPath { get; set; }                  // Contains the geometric path to draw this folder and its tab.
        public Visibility FolderVisible { get; set; }           // This folder's Show/Hide flag.

        public Folder(int Number, string Label, double Top, SolidColorBrush Brush, string FolderPath, Visibility FolderVisible)
        {
            this.Number = Number;
            this.Label = Label;
            this.Top = Top;
            this.Brush = Brush;
            this.FolderPath = FolderPath;
            this.FolderVisible = FolderVisible;
        }
    }

    public class Folders : ObservableCollection<Folder>
    {

        public static ObservableCollection<Folder> Me = null;

        private static string[] Labels = new string[]
        {
            "Personal",
            "Health",
            "Finances",
            "Home",
            "Employment",
            "Insurance",
            "Documents",
            "Contacts",
            "Journal"
        };

        private static Dictionary<string, Tuple<bool, bool>> LabelData = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<bool, bool>>()
        {//  Label                            Show  Hidable
            {Labels[0], new Tuple<bool, bool>(true, false)},
            {Labels[1], new Tuple<bool, bool>(true, true)},
            {Labels[2], new Tuple<bool, bool>(true, true)},
            {Labels[3], new Tuple<bool, bool>(true, true)},
            {Labels[4], new Tuple<bool, bool>(true, true)},
            {Labels[5], new Tuple<bool, bool>(true, true)},
            {Labels[6], new Tuple<bool, bool>(true, true)},
            {Labels[7], new Tuple<bool, bool>(true, false)},
            {Labels[8], new Tuple<bool, bool>(true, true)}
        };

        private static string[] FolderColors = new string[]
        {
            "FF36579E",
            "FFDF2024",
            "FF16A146",
            "FF00B2D4",
            "FFF47B20",
            "FF9F1F63",
            "FF13A89E",
            "FFB7B7E7",
            "FF50CAF5",
            "FFAA9E74",
            "FF86787D",
            "FF36D146",
        };

        private static byte[] ARGBColor = new byte[4];         // Byte array for the folder top color.
        private static void ColorString2ARGB(ref byte[] bytes, string Hex)
        {// Converts 8 char hex string to 4 byte array.
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i += 2)
                bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(Hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        }

        private static int colorIndex = -1; // Initial value of the colorIndex.
        private static string NextColor()
        {// Returns a 8 char string containing the next top FolderColor.  If at end, cycle to beginning.
            colorIndex++;
            if (colorIndex >= FolderColors.Length) colorIndex = 0;
            return FolderColors[colorIndex];
        }

        private class FolderShow
        {
            public string Label { get; set; }
            public bool Show { get; set; }
            public bool Hidable { get; set; }
            public FolderShow(string label, bool show, bool hidable)
            {
                Label = label;
                Show = show;
                Hidable = hidable;
            }
        }
        private static List<FolderShow> FolderShowList = null;

        public static Popup FolderShowPopUp()
        {
            var pu = new Popup()
            {
                Placement = PlacementMode.Right,
                AllowsTransparency = true,
                StaysOpen = false
            };
            var b = new Border()
            {
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(2),
                BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush() { Color = Colors.Black },
                CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(5),
                Background = new SolidColorBrush() { Color = Colors.White }
            };
            var sp = new StackPanel()
            {
                Orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                Margin = new Thickness(10)
            };
            var tb = new TextBlock()
            {
                Text = "Checked Folders will be Displayed: ",
                FontSize = 16,
                FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
            };

            sp.Children.Add(tb);

            foreach (var fs in FolderShowList)
            {
                var cb = new CheckBox()
                {
                    Content = fs.Label,
                    IsChecked = fs.Show,
                    IsEnabled = fs.Hidable,
                    FontSize = 14,
                    FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
                    Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0)
                };
                cb.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Event_CheckBoxFolderList_Click);
                sp.Children.Add(cb);
            }

            var bp = new StackPanel()
            {
                Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
                Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0)
            };
            var ba = new Button() { Content = "Apply", Width = 50, Height = 25, BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent), Tag = pu };
            ba.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Event_ApplyFolderList_Click);
            bp.Children.Add(ba);
            var bc = new Button() { Content = "Cancel", Width = 50, Height = 25, BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent), Tag = pu, Margin = new Thickness(7, 0, 0, 0) };
            bc.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Event_CancelFolderList_Click);
            bp.Children.Add(bc);
            sp.Children.Add(bp);

            var tbm = new TextBlock()
            {
                Text = "Disabled folders cannot be hidden.",
                Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0),
                FontSize = 12,
                Foreground = new SolidColorBrush()  { Color = Colors.Red }
            };
            sp.Children.Add(tbm);

            b.Child = sp;
            pu.Child = b;

            return pu;
        }

        private static void Event_CheckBoxFolderList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var cb = (CheckBox)e.Source;
            foreach (var fs in FolderShowList)
            {
                if (fs.Label == cb.Content as string)
                {
                    fs.Show = (bool)cb.IsChecked;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private static void Event_CancelFolderList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((Popup)((Button)e.Source).Tag).IsOpen = false;
        }

        private static void Event_ApplyFolderList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var fs in FolderShowList)
            {
                var sh = LabelData[fs.Label];
                LabelData[fs.Label] = new Tuple<bool, bool>(fs.Show, sh.Item2);
            }
            ((Popup)((Button)e.Source).Tag).IsOpen = false;

            int p = 0;
            foreach (var f in Me)
            {
                var fs = LabelData[f.Label].Item1 == true;
                f.Top = p * folderPositionFactor;
                f.FolderVisible = fs ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
                if (fs) p += 1;
            }
            foreach (ItemsControl ic in GD.MainWindow.xFolders.Children)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ic.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    var ie = (UIElement)ic.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
                    var iec = Controls.FindChildByType<Canvas>(ie, "FolderCanvas");
                    if (iec != null)
                    {
                        var f = Me[i];
                        Canvas.SetTop(iec, f.Top);          // Why does this not work and
                        iec.Visibility = f.FolderVisible;   // this does work?
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            GD.Refresh.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
        }

        public static void Placement(ref ListBox lb)
        {
            lb.Items.Clear();
            foreach (ItemsControl ic in GD.MainWindow.xFolders.Children)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ic.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    var ie = (UIElement)ic.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
                    var iec = Controls.FindChildByType<Canvas>(ie, "FolderCanvas");
                    if (iec != null)
                    {
                        var f = Me[i];
                        lb.Items.Add(f.Label + ": " + f.Top.ToString() + ", " + (f.FolderVisible == Visibility.Visible ? "True" : "False"));
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }


        public Folders()
        {// The constructor, initializes itself by creating a folder for each label in Labels
            FolderShowList = new List<FolderShow>();
            for (int i = 0; i < Labels.Length; i++)
            {
                string n = Labels[i];
                bool h = LabelData[Labels[i]].Item2;
                bool s = h == true ? LabelData[Labels[1]].Item1 == true : true;
                FolderShowList.Add(new FolderShow(n, s, h));
            }
            SetFolders();
            Me = this;
        }

        const double folderPositionFactor = 31; // 21.80;
        public void SetFolders()
        {
            SolidColorBrush[] scb = new SolidColorBrush[Labels.Length];           // Hold the linear solid color brush to assign to the folder.
            Color[] pointerColor = new Color[Labels.Length];                      // Hold the color to assign to the folder's solid color brush.

            for (int i = 0; i < Labels.Length; i++)
            {// Create a solid color brush for each folder.
                ColorString2ARGB(ref ARGBColor, NextColor());                                               // Color into byte array.
                Color TmpColor = Color.FromArgb(ARGBColor[0], ARGBColor[1], ARGBColor[2], ARGBColor[3]);    // Create top color.
                pointerColor[i] = TmpColor;
                SolidColorBrush TmpSCB = new SolidColorBrush() { Color = TmpColor };
                scb[i] = TmpSCB; // Assign the solid color brush.
            }

            // All is ready to create the individual folders.
            const string folderHeight = "56"; // "44";
            Brush FontColor = Brushes.Black;                                          // Initial font color for labels.
            string fp = "M0,7 A7,7 90 0 1 7,0 L100,0 105,18 150,18 150,FH 0,FH Z".Replace("FH", folderHeight);  // Initial geometric path for folder design.
            int afp = 0; // Actual Folder Position.
            for (int i = 0; i < Labels.Length; i++)
            {// Create the individual folders.
                bool fs = FolderShowList[i].Show;
                Add(new Folder(
                                i + 1,                                          // Folder sequence count.
                                Labels[i],                                      // Folder label.
                                afp * folderPositionFactor,                     // Position of top of folder.
                                scb[i % scb.Length],                            // Solid color brush.
                                fp,                                             // Geometric path for folder design.
                                fs ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed  // User Hidden.
                              )
                        );
                if (fs) afp += 1;
                if (i == 0)
                {// First folder created, now set values for remaining folders.
                    FontColor = Brushes.White;
                    fp = "M0,25 A7,7 90 0 1 7,18 L13,18 18,0 100,0 105,18 150,18 150,FH 0,FH Z".Replace("FH", folderHeight);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Controls
    {

        public static T FindChildByType<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            if (parent == null) return null; // No parent, get out of here.
            T foundChild = null;
            int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                // If the child is not of the request child type child
                T childType = child as T;
                if (childType == null)
                {
                    // recursively drill down the tree
                    foundChild = FindChildByType<T>(child, childName);

                    // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
                    if (foundChild != null) break;
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
                {
                    var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
                    // If the child's name is set for search
                    if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
                    {
                        // if the child's name is of the request name
                        foundChild = (T)child;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // child element found.
                    foundChild = (T)child;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return foundChild;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help that you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the answer, and it is very simple.

This is the code to be changed (the center line only):

```
                    var f = Me[i];
                    Canvas.SetTop(iec, f.Top);          // Why does this not work
                    iec.Visibility = f.FolderVisible;   // and this does work?
```

This is the new code (only the center line is changed, actually, only one character is removed):

```
                    var f = Me[i];
                    Canvas.SetTop(ie, f.Top);
                    iec.Visibility = f.FolderVisible;
```

That is, change `Canvas.SetTop(iec, f.Top);` to `Canvas.SetTop(ie, f.Top);` that is, only change `iec` to `ie` and all works fine.

Comment: An `ItemsControl` wraps each element in a `ContentPresenter`, and you need to be sure you're setting `Canvas.Top` on the `ContentPresenter`, not the item inside the `ItemTemplate`. That is what the `ItemContainerStyle` does - it sets the value on the `ContentPresenter`